# how to convert multiple documents in a directory in base64 string and save in a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to convert multiple resumes in a particular directory into base64 
string and save it to the text file at a same time.

What I tried so far

```py
import base64
import sys

with open("filename.pdf", "rb") as pdf_file , open("filename.pdf","w") as output:
    encoded_string = base64.b64encode(pdf_file.read(),output.write())

I got this error when I execute the code

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "encode.py", line 5, in <module>
    encoded_string = base64.b64encode(pdf_file.read(),output.write())
TypeError: write() takes exactly one argument (0 given)
```

Comment: have you read the documentation for the functions you are using?

Comment: What made you think that ˋ...,output.write() would do what you want?

Comment: @njzk2 do you have the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

```
output.write(base64.b64encode(pdf_file.read()))
```

or:

```
encoded_string = base64.b64encode(pdf_file.read())
output.write(encoded_string)
```

Comment: still it throw the same output